# `python` in CMD returns " `python` is not recognized ..."

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd, pythonxy

Python 2.7 is installed on `C:/Python27` (through python(x,y) package). Windows 8.1 x64. How do I make Python 2.7 run from CMD ?

I want to do this as I am following "Learn Python The Hard Way" book and I got stuck on Excercise 0: The Setup.

I have tried:

- Powershell `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")`
- Adding Python to Windows PATH (both through the Control Panel and terminal).
- Copying a python.bat file with `@C:\Python27\python.exe %*` to the system32.
- Running CMD both as adminstrator and the regualr way.
- Restarting CMD and PC between operations.

Both `python` and `call python` executed in CMD return `'python' is not recognized` message. If I enter in CMD `C:\Python27\python.exe` then Python starts properly.

User variable Path for me:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\vtk;C:\Python27\gnuplot\binary;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\SciTE-3.3.2-3;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\console;C:\MinGW32-xy\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\swig;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\gettext\bin
```

System variable Path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\vtk;C:\Python27\gnuplot\binary;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\SciTE-3.3.2-3;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\console;C:\MinGW32-xy\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\swig;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\gettext\bin
```

Comment: [Using Python on Windows](http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#configuring-python)

Comment: What's the output of `echo %PATH%` cmd in your command line console?

Comment: `echo %PATH%` returns bunch of stuff and python folder is there. But it is twice - might that be an issue ?

Comment: Ashwini Chaudhary, that set command did not help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by not using python(x,y). I decided to switch because I did read that author of python(x,y) did not rely on official packages. Installed Anaconda - everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the location of the files in the PATH environment variable. Follow the steps: Go to My Computer->Right click->Properties->Advanced System Settings->Click Environmental Variables. Now click PATH and then click EDIT. In the variable value field, go to the end and append ';' (without quotes) and then add the absolute path of the .exe file which you want to run via your program.

Comment: Added `C:\Python27\python.exe` to system variable Path and ran `python` in CMD both with and without 'Run as adminsitrator'. No effect.

Comment: You only need to add the path, `C:\Python27\` into the environment variable, not the complete path to the executable

Comment: That one I already have added as you can see in question text under code sections of user and system paths.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using an old cmd line window, check if `C:\Python27;` is really added to your current cmd line window's path by typing `echo %path%` (don't check this via control pannel), if it's not there, start a new cmd window. Then probably `C:\Python27;` will be there in %PATH% and *python* will be recognized as a cmd now.

Comment: `echo %path%` returns `C:\Python27;`, as well as other entries.

Comment: @Kalstrams that doesn't make sense, paste your output of `echo %path% & python` here or at codepad.org.